# authentication exchange unsuccessful [Postgresql Error] [Kong Gateway]

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, kong

i tried to set up kong gateway with postgresql using ubuntu 18.04 bionic.
using documentation etc i got the following error :

```
Error: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve PostgreSQL server_version_num: authentication exchange unsuccessful

  Run with --v (verbose) or --vv (debug) for more details
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be a tls issue, can you share `KONG_PG_SSL` and  `KONG_PG_SSL_VERIFY` values ? Have you check you can connect to postgresql with the credential with a client ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason was that they noticed

> Older versions of PostgreSQL use ident authentication by default,
> newer versions (PSQL 10+) use scram-sha-256. To allow the kong user to
> communicate with the database locally, change the authentication
> method to md5 by modifying the PostgreSQL configuration file.

If using PSQL 10 + we have to do the above mentioned change.

how to change :

change directory

```
cd /etc/postgresql/{your_psql_vertion}/main
```

1.Uncomment and change postgresql.conf as follows

```
authentication_timeout = 1min 
password_encryption = md5
```

2.change pg_hba.conf if need as fllows

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Comment: Does this only apply to local PostgreSQL installations? If MD5 must be used for a network-connected PostgreSQL server then this poses a security risk which should be mitigated by the Kong authors.